# Swift alternative to using instance member as default parameter

Tags: swift

Here is a toy version of my problem:

```swift
class MainClass {
    let toPass: ToPassProtocol
    let otherClass: BbbProtocol
    init(
        toPass: ToPassProtocol,
        otherClass: Bbb = Bbb(toPass: toPass)
    ) {
        self.toPass = toPass
        self.otherClass = otherClass
    }
}

class Bbb: BbbProtocol {
    let toPass: ToPassProtocol
    init(toPass: ToPassProtocol) {
        self.toPass = toPass
    }
}

protocol ToPassProtocol {}
class ToPass: ToPassProtocol {}

protocol BbbProtocol {}
```

Which gives the error `Cannot use instance member toPass as a default Parameter`

So without using a function to pass `ToPassProtocol` after initialisation, how can I pass this class as, well, a parameter?

Answer (score -1):

if you already have the toPass being passed, change your init function to use the passed parameter and have the other default to nil:

```
    init(
        toPass: ToPassProtocol,
        otherClass: Bbb? = nil
    ) {
        if let otherClass = otherClass {
          self.otherClass = otherClass
        } else {
          self.otherClass = Bbb(toPass: toPass)
        }
        self.toPass = toPass
    }
```